# helpを表示する際の終了コードはどのようにすべきか

Tags: command-line

Go言語でコマンドラインツールを書いているのですが、
一つ分からないことがあります。

コマンドのオプションに--helpを渡された場合、
コマンドの使い方のみ表示して終了するのが普通だと思いますが、
その際の終了コードはどのようにすべきでしょうか？

GitHub上にあるいくつかのコマンドラインツールを試してみると、
peco、ghq、hubなどの終了コードは0、
jvgrep、gocode、hkなどの終了コードは2となっており、
0と2、どちらにすべきか分かりませんでした。

Comment: 本題ではないですが、golang はあまり関係ないですね。usage 表示を行った後、どういう終了コードを返すかの話なので python でも ruby でもありえます。

Comment: タグをcommand-lineに変更しました。

Comment: 2の由来は[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)の"Misuse of shell builtins (according to Bash documentation)"と考えられます。ただし、明示的に--helpを渡す操作をmisuseというかは意見が分かれそうですね。

Comment: jvgrepのhelpは[常に失敗扱い](https://github.com/mattn/jvgrep/blob/v4.1/jvgrep.go#L515)のようですが、gocodeは[helpコマンドを定義していない](https://github.com/nsf/gocode/blob/v.20150303/gocode.go#L14-20)ので[flagパッケージの仕様によりエラー扱い](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#pkg-variables)ですし、hkもflagを使ってますが[helpコマンドを指定すれば成功扱い](https://github.com/heroku/hk/blob/v20140604/help.go#L102-105)、と様々ですね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そのコマンドが--helpというオプションを定義しているなら、指示されたオプション(ヘルプを表示する)を正しく実行したということで0にすべきだし、—-helpというオプションを定義しているわけではなくて、不正オプションが指示された場合helpメッセージを表示する仕様にしているなら、
指示が誤っているということで2にすればよいと思います。

全てを調べたわけではありませんが、例えばpecoコマンドは--helpオプションがあることが説明されていますし、jvgrepコマンドは--helpオプションがあるとは書かれていません。

Comment: jvgrepに限って言えば、オプションが間違っているときの短いヘルプで、[「詳しくは `jvgrep --help' を見ろ」といったメッセージを出す](https://github.com/mattn/jvgrep/blob/v4.1/jvgrep.go#L474)ようです。

Comment: helpというオプションが定義されているか否かで終了コードが決まるということでしょうか。
それならばGo言語のflagパッケージは--helpが渡された際、デフォルトではusage表示をして終了コード2で終了し、`flag.bool("help", ...)`などでhelpオプションの定義がされている場合は終了せず処理が続行する仕様になっているので、確かに納得がいきます。
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/flag/flag.go#l846-854